# Where are we going?

Tags: riddle, visual

Randall is on vacation in Australia, and his older sister has planned out the whole thing.

One night, when they've returned to their hotel room, she hands him a slip of paper and says, "This is where we'll be going tomorrow. See if you can figure it out."

[image: A map with a strange path written on it]

Randall looks at the slip of paper, bewildered and puzzled. Just where *are* they going?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> They are going to [Uluru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uluru), a sandstone rock formation in Australia, as hinted by the first letter of the directions Up, Left, Up, Right, Up.

Comment: Quick as a lightning bolt! Yep, that's the answer.

Comment: This was a case of, "Is that actually a thing? That can't be a thing. Well, let me Google it."

Comment: Well, you now know it's a thing.